# Python script to copy-paste range of cells in Excel files

Tags: python, excel

I'm trying to copy a range of columns starting in cell A2 from one Excel file and pasting into another Excel file. When I run the script I don't get any errors, but nothing happens. One thing I noticed is that in Notepadd++ it appears some of the code doesn't highlight like it should, for example the wb= openpyxl.load_workbook is just plain text and not colored blue like some of the other actions in the file and not sure if that is causing my issue. Here is the code I'm using:

`#! Python 3
# - Copy and Paste Ranges using OpenPyXl library

```
import openpyxl

#Prepare the spreadsheets to copy from and paste too.

 

#File to be copied
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook("Current_Comments.xlsx") #Add file name
sheet = wb["Sheet1"] #Add Sheet name

#File to be pasted into
template = openpyxl.load_workbook("Current_Comments2.xlsx") #Add file 
name
temp_sheet = template["Sheet1"] #Add Sheet name

#Copy range of cells as a nested list
#Takes: start cell, end cell, and sheet you want to copy from.
def copyRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, sheet):
    rangeSelected = []
    #Loops through selected Rows
    for i in range(startRow,endRow + 1,1):
        #Appends the row to a RowSelected list
        rowSelected = []
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            rowSelected.append(sheet.cell(row = i, column = j).value)
        #Adds the RowSelected List and nests inside the rangeSelected
        rangeSelected.append(rowSelected)

    return rangeSelected
         

#Paste range
#Paste data from copyRange into template sheet
def pasteRange(startCol, startRow, endCol, endRow, 
sheetReceiving,copiedData):
    countRow = 0
    for i in range(startRow,endRow+1,1):
        countCol = 0
        for j in range(startCol,endCol+1,1):
            
            sheetReceiving.cell(row = i, column = j).value = 
copiedData[countRow][countCol]
            countCol += 1
        countRow += 1
def createData():
    print("Processing...")
    selectedRange = copyRange(1,2,19,7500,sheet) #Change the 4 number values
    pastingRange = pasteRange(1,2,19,7500,temp_sheet,selectedRange) #Change 
the 4 number values
    #You can save the template as another file to create a new file here 
too.s
    #template.save("foo.xlsx")
    print("Range copied and pasted!")`
```

Answer (score 0):

try deleting the createData() and run the code within it, without it being a function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).